# Tapestry page junit test

Tags: java, junit, junit4, tapestry

I try to write a junit test for [tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/) 5.4 page rendering:

```
import org.apache.tapestry5.test.PageTester;

public class LoadTest {
    private final String PAGE_NAME = "Login";
    private final String APP_NAME = "";
    private final String context = "src/main/webapp";
    private PageTester tester;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        String appPackage = "hu.webapp";
        tester = new PageTester(appPackage, APP_NAME, context, AppModule.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void confirmIndexIsLoaded() {
        Document document = new Document();
        document = tester.renderPage(PAGE_NAME);
        assertNotNull(document);
    }
}
```

But I got an `RuntimeException`, and it said  `Request was not handled: 'Login' may not be a valid page name.`

But this is a working page in my webapp, and it renders well.

Have somebody any idea(s) what's wrong with test or can somebody shows me a similar working test code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, this only happens when you inform the wrong `package` for your page's package. Take a look (it works for me):

```
import org.apache.tapestry5.test.PageTester;

public class LoadTest {
    private final String PAGE_NAME = "Login"; // It has to be right too!
    private final String APP_NAME = "app"; // Where was your app name?
    private final String context = "src/main/webapp"; // Is that path right in your project?
    private PageTester tester;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        String appPackage = "hu.webapp"; // Check if that's really correct!!!
        tester = new PageTester(appPackage, APP_NAME, context);
    }

    @Test
    public void confirmIndexIsLoaded() {
        Document document = tester.renderPage(PAGE_NAME);
        assertNotNull(document);
    }
}
```

Also, check your `app` name, it should have been configured at your web.xml as the Tapestry filter, like in, e.g.:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>app</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>app</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. Actually there is a lack of information about tapestry testing.. I read some articles.. but every article suggest different stuff.. so in the end they confused me.. so it became kind a "black-box test"..
anyway the `context` means the absolute path of my project or a relative path of something?

Comment: I figured out! 
    `private final String PAGE_NAME = "Login";
    private final String APP_NAME = "app";
    private final String context = "src/main";`
and I left the ".ui" ending of  `appPackage` 

thx for the help